# Templating Class Relationship

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
template<class Rawr>
class TestContains;

template <class T>
class TestStore//: public TestContains
{
public:
    TestStore(T first, T second, T W, T H)
    {
        x = first;
        y = second;
        Width = W;
        Height = H;

        TestContains<T> a(x, y, Width, Height);

        *b = a;
    }
    ~TestStore() {};


    T x;
    T y;
    T Width;
    T Height;

TestContains<T>* GetRect();

protected:
private:
TestContains<T> *b;
};
```

The CPP

```
template<class T>
TestContains<T>* TestStore<T>::GetRect()
{
    return &b;
}
```

Test Contains

```
template<class Rawr>
class TestContains
{
    public:
        TestContains(Rawr first, Rawr second,  Rawr W, Rawr H)
        {
            x = first;
            y = second;
            Width = W;
            Height = H;
        }

        ~TestContains(){};

    template <class T>
    bool Contains(T Mx, T My)
    {
       if (Mx >= x && Mx <= x + Width && My >= y && My <= My + Height)
       return true;

       return false;
    }

Rawr x;
Rawr y;
Rawr Width;
Rawr Height;

///friend?
template<class T>
friend class TestStore;

    protected:
    private:
};
```

Implementation

```
TestStore<int> test(0, 0, 100, 100);

if (test.GetRect().Contains(mouseX, mouseY))
{
    std::cout << "Within 0, 0, 100, 100" << std::endl;
}
```

ANYWAY... so I cannot compile this as I get

> /home/chivos/Desktop/yay/ShoeState.cpp||In member function ‘virtual void ShoeState::GameLoop(GameEngine*)’:|
>   /home/chivos/Desktop/yay/ShoeState.cpp|51|error: request for member ‘Contains’ in ‘test.TestStore::GetRect with T = int’, which is of non-class type ‘TestContains*’|
>   ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I have been messing with this for a long time and it is starting to bother me! lol, does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems: One is pointed out by sftrabbit in his/her answer. The other is that you try to return a pointer-to-pointer in the `GetRect` function: Using the address-of `&` operator will make the return statement return the address of the pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

You have an even more serious problem than the compilation errors though, one that is *undefined behavior* and will most likely end up with a crash: In the class `TestStore` you have the member variable `b` which is a pointer. In the constructor you assign to what it points to, but at that time it doesn't actually point to anything and you overwrite random memory.

Either allocate the pointer before using the dereference operator to assign to where it points, or don't use a pointer at all (my recommendation).

Comment: I got ya!! Thank you very much. I think my question has been answered!!

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `test.GetRect()` returns a pointer. To access a member through a pointer to an object, you should use `->` instead of `.`:

```
//                ▾▾
if (test.GetRect()->Contains(mouseX, mouseY))
{
    std::cout << "Within 0, 0, 100, 100" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Lol, I feel kind of dumb for that! That fixed that problem. Now I am getting an undefined reference to TestStore<int>::GetRect()

Comment: @Chivos That's because you can't split templated classes into separate header and source files. All functions have to be fully defined in the header file.